# Google Refine split string into multiple columns using multiple separators

Tags: openrefine

I am new to OpenRefine.

I would like to split a string such as the two examples below below into different columns.

EXAMPLE1: /articles/the_year_of_cooking_6_ways_to_make_2014_meals_your_best?affref=whatever

EXAMPLE2: /?Article=younger_looking_everything_5_tips_for_aging_well&affref=anotherwhatever

The first example should be divided into three columns:

/articles/
the year of cooking 6 ways to make 2014 meals your best?
affref=whatever

The second example should be divided into three columns:

/?Article=
younger looking everything in 5 tips for aging well
&affref=anotherwhatever

Edit Column>Split doesn't seem to allow for different separators ("/", "=", "&")

Edit Column > Add Column Based on This Column seems right but I don't know enough about regular expressions or GREL to make it happen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two separate Split operations with the different separate or you could learn enough about regular expressions to do it in one.  Character classes are defined using square brackets, do using  regular expression separator of [/?] or [/&?] should do the trick.  I haven't tested this, so you may need to escape any characters that are considered special.

Answer (score 0):

Edit cells > Add column based on this column

```
substring(value, lastIndexOf(value, "/")+1, lastIndexOf(value, "?")+1)
```

The above GREL gets a substring between "/" and "?" characters. It works by getting the numerical indices of your delimiting characters with the `lastIndexOf()` function. Then, then those indices are used with `substring()` to grab a middle portion of the string. And `+1` is added to each index to fine-tune which characters end up within the substring.

This will create an OpenRefine column matching the middle column in your example #1. But it will not touch example #2, which has no characters between "/" and "?". Your requested middle column for example #2 can be created with:

```
substring(value, lastIndexOf(value, "Article=")+8, lastIndexOf(value, "&"))
```

The other columns can be created with similar variations on [the substring function](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#substring). When you're finished, your data will be spread over various columns which you can then [add back together](http://kb.refinepro.com/2011/07/move-data-from-column-to-other.html) however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've built an Excel sheet to do up to 15 delimiters, If you wanted to check out the principles I used they are explained on the sheet

https://exeterhealth.libguides.com/ld.php?content_id=33701878

Would like to know if this level of functionality can be achieved easily in openrefine...

David Newman  Exeter Health Library Devon  UK